# How to wait for list of `Future`s created using different `ExecutorServices`

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, future

Ok, so I know the first answer / comment here will be "use one `ExecutorService` and use `invokeAll`". However, there is a good reason (which I will not bore people with) for us keeping the thread pools separate.

So I have a list of thread pools (`ExecutorServices`) and what I need to do is invoke a different `Callable` on each thread pool using `submit` (no problem there). Now I have this collection of `Future` instances, each created on a seperate `ExecutorService`, and I want to wait for all of them to complete (**and be able to provide a timeout at which any not done are cancelled**).

Is there an existing class that will do this (wrap a list of `Future` instances and allow for a wait till all are done)? If not, suggestions on an efficient mechanism would be appreciated.

Was thinking of calling `get` with a timeout for each but have to do a calculation of the total time passed for each call.

I saw this post [Wait Until Any of Future is Done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117690/wait-until-any-of-futuret-is-done) but this extends `Future` instead of wrapping a list of them.

Comment: for each that list and when the last one is done its done - as they say

Comment: Updated post to make it clear that the timeout is the thing that is the issue and I am hoping to not reinvent the wheel in that regard.

Comment: well if you read those nifty lil' java docs you will see that you can AwaitTermination and set the timeout then when you submit your tasks you can send it a shutdown and if the task dont complete in time it ill shutdown after ur timeout wabamzorz!!!!

Comment: Where in his question did he say that the Executor will be shutdown?

Comment: You could do this if these were Guava `ListeningExecutorService`s...

Comment: @TylerHeiks Thanks for the insulting comment. If you will read my post I specifically stated that I was using Futures produced from multiple `ExecutorServices`

Comment: @LouisWasserman The `Futures` are produces using a set of services (not a single executor service)

Comment: Eh.  If you can wrap each individual service in [`MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(service)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#listeningDecorator(java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService)), you can turn them all into `ListeningExecutorService`s.  Then you could do [`Futures.allAsList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...)) to create a "joined" future.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You are the MAN! You pointed me in the right direction. Should have known Guava would have what I need. I actually need [Futures.successfulAsList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per Louis' comment, what I was looking for was [Futures.successfulAsList](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...-)

This allows me to wait for all to complete and then check for any futures that failed.

Guava RULES!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think JDK provides a direct API that lets you do that. However, I think it is equally straightforward to create a simple method that does this. You might want to take a look at the implementation of AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll() to get an idea that this can be done.

Essentially, you would call future.get() on each future, decreasing the wait time by the time it took to wait for the result each time, and before returning from the method cancel all outstanding futures.

Comment: +1 Concur. I had thought of that and included it in my post as the obvious mechanism. I was hoping there was a better / already implemented mechanism and someone else knew of.

Comment: That's probably as good an implementation as you can get. It would have been straightforward for the JDK creators to provide that as a stand-alone (static) method. Another implementation might involve using a completion service and waiting in the order the tasks are completed. However, code becomes bit more involved with little additional benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't really get it. However, to me it still sounds as simple as

```
public <V> List<V> get(List<Future<V>> futures, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
          throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    List<V> result = new ArrayList<V>();
    long end = System.nanoTime() + unit.toNanos(timeout);
    for (Future<V> f: futures) {
        result.add(f.get(end - System.nanoTime(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Am I wrong with that?

The question you link is much more complex I think, as they only want to wait for the fastest, and of course have no idea which will be the fastest.

Comment: +1 The issue with this is that `get` can throw an exception. Changing it to return the `Futures` after they are all done would help. Also, it does not handle the shutdown. This is the obvious implementation, I was wanting to see if there was something cleaner / already implemented as tested.

Answer (score 1):

This could use some cleanup, but it should solve your problem. (Some encapsulation omitted for time and space):

```
public static <T> LatchWithWrappedCallables<T> wrapCallables(Collection<Callable<T>> callablesToWrap)
{
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(callablesToWrap.size());
    List<Callable<T>> wrapped = new ArrayList<Callable<T>>(callablesToWrap.size());
    for (Callable<T> currCallable : callablesToWrap)
    {
        wrapped.add(new CallableCountdownWrapper<T>(currCallable, latch));
    }

    LatchWithWrappedCallables<T> returnVal = new LatchWithWrappedCallables<T>();
    returnVal.latch = latch;
    returnVal.wrappedCallables = wrapped;
    return returnVal;
}

public static class LatchWithWrappedCallables<T>
{
    public CountDownLatch latch;
    public Collection<Callable<T>> wrappedCallables;
}

public static class CallableCountdownWrapper<T> implements Callable<T>
{
    private final Callable<T> wrapped;

    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    public CallableCountdownWrapper(Callable<T> wrapped, CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            return wrapped.call();
        }
        finally
        {
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your code would call it like this:

```
Collection<Callable<String>> callablesToWrap = [Your callables that you need to wait for here];
LatchWithWrappedCallables<String> latchAndCallables = wrapCallables(callablesToWrap);

[Submit the wrapped callables to the executors here]

if(latchAndCallables.latch.await(timeToWaitInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
{
    [Handling for timeout here]
}
```

Comment: And on second thought, I think that I would probably roll the await directly into the LatchWithWrappedCallables class to make it even easier. (And yes, "LatchWithWrappedCallables" is a terrible name!)

Comment: I will give this some deeper thought tomorrow to see if it fits my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. I need to look at the ListenableFuture thing too.

Comment: Turns out [Futures.successfulAsList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#successfulAsList(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...)) is what I was looking for